# shortcut not opening app on android homescreen

Tags: java, android

I have installed a few apps on my android device, and I developed a code to create a shortcut for them, they all work apart from one app, but if I manually drag the app on homescreen it works, I'm really confused... the next code is what I used to create the shortcuts

```
try
        {
        //Log.i("shortcut method in androidhelper start","in the shortcutapp on create method ");
        boolean flag =false ;
        int app_id=-1;
        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
        List<ResolveInfo> res =p.queryIntentActivities( i,0);
        //System.out.println("the res size is: "+res.size());

        for(int k=0;k<res.size();k++)
        {
        //Log.i("","the application name is: "+res.get(k).activityInfo.loadLabel(p));
        if(res.get(k).activityInfo.loadLabel(p).toString().equals("Kortext")){
        flag = true;
        app_id = k;
        break;
        }
        }

        if(flag)
        {
        ActivityInfo ai = res.get(app_id).activityInfo;
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
        shortcutIntent.setClassName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        // Sets the custom shortcut's title
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Kortext");

        BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)(res.get(app_id).activityInfo.loadIcon(p).getCurrent());
        Bitmap newbit;
        newbit=bd.getBitmap();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, newbit);

        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
        else
        {
    //  throw new UserException(UserException.KErrGeneral,"Application not found");
        }

        }

        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw new UserException(UserException.KErrGsmRRNoActivityOnRadioPath,e.getMessage()); 
        }


        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw new UserException(UserException.KErrGeneral,e.getMessage());

        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I also had to change the intents to new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);